# ms dynamics crm 2011 define specific fields for data import templates

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have an entity which has around 15 fields on it. When users download the data import template,  all the 15 fields are included and displayed in Excel (as expected).

I would like to hide/exclude some of these fields as they are only populated 
at a later stage. I believe CRM uses the main form of the entity to create the template (I stand corrected on this).

Is there a way to generate the template based on another form? or achieve the above with some work around?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

I could not completely achieve what I wanted, but implemented a work around.
I ended up exporting the template, removing columns I wanted to hide from the user and then placing the new template in a central location for copying and importing.

Answer (score 1):

They are generated based on your current view. Create a new view by selecting only fields you want or do an advanced find by adding only columns you want and then export.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I found that the 'Export to Excel' function uses the current view, however the import data -> "download template for import" includes all columns, regardless of the current view.